# How to list users and their post amount?

Tags: posts, users

I want to list all the users of my site and the amount of posts each user has.

So far I have the function below, but I don't know how to pull in each user's ID to use in the count_user_posts...

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ( get_users('order=DESC&orderby=post_count') as $user ) : ?>
    <li style="color:#fff;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">
    <?php echo $user->display_name; ?></span> as <?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?> (<?php echo $user->post_count; ?> Posts)<br />
    <?php echo 'Posts made: ' . count_user_posts(1); ?>
    </li><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I have foreach function going, but count_user_posts requires an integer I don't pull in each individual user ID to grab their post amount.

I would appreciate some help with this. I know it's probably something simple... I'm kind of new to php :D. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has a [wp_list_authors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors) function with the option to list post count.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'orderby' => 'post_count', 'optioncount' => true);
wp_list_authors( $args );
?>
```

EDIT: While it's possible to do it the way you're doing it and use count_user_posts(), this will trigger a query to retrieve users, then additional queries to get each user's count. this is a very inefficient way to do this and may have a significant impact on performance if you have a lot of authors. A better way is to select users, and count the posts all in one query. If you look in `wp-includes/author-template.php` you'll see the query `wp_list_authors` generates to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo 'Posts made: ' . count_user_posts($user->ID); ?>
```